# How do i send xml file to http request in python and what are the packages that need to be installed in ubuntu

Tags: python, http

How do i send xml file to http request(to web url) in python 2.7 or 3.3 or 3.4 and what are the packages that need to be installed in ubuntu..

Comment: It depends on how do you want to send the file e.g., as is, or as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, or `multipart/form-data`. Is it a regular file on disk? Do you need to stream it (is it large)? Have you tried `urllib2`, `requests` modules?

Comment: thanks for the replay.

this my file content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request async="false" id="139" tid="" tsn="354" type="LIVE" lat="" long="" version="1.7" ram="478" diskSpace="9316" battery="25" unsyncTransactions="0"/>

file name example.xml

url will be like 

:192.168.6.x:9090/test/request?

Comment: 'code' import requests
url = "http://192.168.6.x:8089/test/request?"
files ="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Request async="false" id="139" tid="" tsn="354" type="LIVE" lat="" long="" version="1.7" ram="478" diskSpace="9316" battery="25" unsyncTransactions="0"/> """
r = requests.post(url, str(files))
print (r.text)
print(r.elapsed) 'code'

Comment: this thing solved my issue.

Comment: don't put additional info in the comments, [update your question instead](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23075224/edit). If you think you found an answer; you could [post it as your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: new this one thanks for the guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import requests url = "192.168.6.x:8089/test/request?"; files ="""  """ r = requests.post(url, str(files)) print (r.text) print(r.elapsed)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
with open(f"/tmp/{filename}") as xml:
    files = {'file': xml}
    response = requests.post(url=complete_url, verify=CA_CERT, cert=(TLS_CERT, TLS_KEY), files=files, timeout=600)
    response.raise_for_status()
```